# How to make ToggleButton from MUI horizontally scrollable once ToggleButtonGroup don't fit to screen width

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, styled-components

I'm making Responsive Web Design in my project and I want to make horizontally scrollable ToggleButton from Mui. The idea is that once screen width will be too little to keep 3 buttons displayed I want then to move one to the side and make the screen horizontally scrollable.
This is how it looks now when width is enough to keep 3 buttons
[image]

In below situation I want to move right side button out of the screen and make it horizontally scrollable
[image]

This is how the ToggleButton in implemented

```
export const StyledToggleButtonGroupWheelsMobile = styled(ToggleButtonGroup)`
    display: flex;
    margin: 12px 16px 9px 11px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    color: ${({ theme }) => theme.palette.white};
`;

export const StyledToggleButtonWheelsMobile = styled(ToggleButton)`
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Poppins;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px 14px 6px 13px;
    border-radius: 4px !important;
    border: none;
    height: 35px;
`;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the Tabs component and
`variant="scrollable" scrollButtons="auto"`

https://mui.com/components/tabs/#scrollable-tabs

Comment: tried this but no idea why it was not scrollable... Do You see any chance to keep Toggle Buttons ? I have it in few places in the app with some logic so would be much easier to keep ToggleButton but add a scrollable option